# Distance calculation in MySQL in the count query

Tags: mysql

I have a user table which has the latitude and longitude information of the users. I am querying users depending upon the distance from a specific lat lon. To speed things up, I can use the distance expression in the `SELECT` statement and use `Having` to filter the results like:

```
SELECT id, 
    (6378.388 * acos(sin(:latitude) * sin(latitude) + 
     cos(:latitude) * cos(latitude) * cos(longitude - :longitude))) as distance
FROM User
Having distance < 60
```

Issue is to paginate the results, I need to use the `Count` function on user id in a duplicate query. How to use the distance expression to filter the exact number of results?

Comment: can you provide a sample input and expected output

Comment: Your query does not seem to be complete. The `from tablename` seems to be missing. Why do you not use `where` instead of the `having` clause for the distance?

Comment: you can't use the expression's alias in where clause, that's why i am using having.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a subquery:

```
select count(id) usrcount from 
(SELECT id, 
(6378.388 * acos(sin(:latitude) * sin(latitude) + 
 cos(:latitude) * cos(latitude) * cos(longitude - :longitude))) as distance
 FROM User) subq
Where distance<60
```

Comment: will there be performance issues for the sub query if I have more than 10000 records?

Comment: Well, that is for you to test first. But if you want to speed up things and your target coordinates are fixed, then you can also first test for long and lat to be within a certain rectangle (without SIN and COS calculations).